# The remote server returned an error: (440) Login Timeout

Tags: c#, exchange-server, webdav

I need to find the mailbox size for the particular account and i have used c# coding with webdav But i am getting error when i used the code .

Please find the error message

> The remote server returned an error: (440) Login Timeout.

Please find the reference link which i have used for code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877932%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

When a HTTP or WebDAV request is issued agains an Exchange 2003 or 2007 public folder or mailbox folder, the server returns a HTTP/1.1 440 Login Timeout error if Form Based authentication is enabled.

See the sample code at http://www.infinitec.de/post/2004/12/Access-the-Exchange-store-via-WebDAV-with-Form-Based-Authentication-turned-on-Updated.aspx