# C# can't read emails with webdav and fba

Tags: c#, exchange-server, webdav, fba

**Summary:**

I am having trouble connecting to an `exchange 2007 mailbox` that is running FBA with my C# code using webdav.

**Details:**

This code below has to work against an exchange 2007 server, connect, and read email from a mailbox.

I've tried EWS but it made no sense and I couldn't get it working.

Below is my code. I am using the outlook url to get the cookies I need to login via webdav to the exchange url.

**Error:**

> ```
> 440 login timeout on the request.
> ```

Area where my code breaks:

```
Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

**Code:**

```
namespace logintomailbox
{
    class Program
    {
        #region auth dont exapnd
        //Authentication to exchange 2007 with webdav and filebasedauth (FBA) in C#
        internal static string dUser = "user";
        internal static string dDomain = "domain";
        internal static string dPassword = "password";
        #endregion
        internal static string MailBoxAliasName = "mailbox;
        internal static string ExchangeServerName = "appews.host.com";
        internal static string outlookServerName = "outlook.host.com";
        internal static string ReadAttachments = "1"; //1 means read attachments, 0 means dont
        internal static string MailBoxEarliestDateToRead = "2011-01-05T00:00:00.000Z";//date of emails to read from

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //FBA code
            //once i get a 302 response code i am authenticated
            DoExchangeFBA("https://" + outlookServerName, dDomain + "/" + dUser, dPassword);

            //login via webdav
            QueryMailBoxViaDAV();

            //exit application
            //ExitProgram((int)ExitReturnCodes.NormalShutdown);
        }
        private static void QueryMailBoxViaDAV()
        {
            //create http web request object
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request;
            //Request.CookieContainer = newCookieContainer();
            //create http web response object
            System.Net.WebResponse Response;

            //create needed components of web request/response
            byte[] bytes = null;
            System.IO.Stream RequestStream = null;
            System.IO.Stream ResponseStream = null;
            XmlDocument ResponseXmlDoc = null;
            string strRootURI = null;

            //check if exchange server is 2007 or 2003                   
            if (ExchangeServerName == "appews.host.com")
            {
                //exchange 2007
                strRootURI = "https://" + ExchangeServerName + "/exchange/" + MailBoxAliasName;
            }
            else
            {
                //exchange 2003
                //example of previously used url for exchange 2003 mailboxes
                strRootURI = "https://" + ExchangeServerName + "/exchange/" + MailBoxAliasName + "/Inbox";
            }

            //begin webdav query
            string strQuery = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D=\"DAV:\" >"
                        + "<D:sql>SELECT \"DAV:displayname\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:message-id\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:date\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:from\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:to\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment\", "
                        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription\" "
                        + " FROM \"" + strRootURI + "\""
                        + "WHERE \"DAV:ishidden\" = false AND \"DAV:isfolder\" = false "
                        + "AND \"urn:schemas:mailheader:date\" > CAST(\"" + MailBoxEarliestDateToRead.ToString() + "\" as \"dateTime.tz\")"
                        + "</D:sql></D:searchrequest>";

            //build http web request
            Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strRootURI);
            Request.KeepAlive = false;
            Request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
               dUser,
               dPassword,
               dDomain);
            Request.Method = "SEARCH";

            //now that everything is created try sending a request
            try
            {
                bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)strQuery);
                Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
                RequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                RequestStream.Close();

                Request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                Request.KeepAlive = true;
                Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
                ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
                ResponseXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                ResponseXmlDoc.Load(ResponseStream);

                ResponseStream.Close();
                Response.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Authentication Successful");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            //catch all exceptions and sent to console if they occur
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        private static CookieCollection DoExchangeFBA(string server, string userName, string password)
        {

            var uri = server + "/owa/auth/owaauth.dll";

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

            server = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(server);
            userName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName);
            password = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
            var bodyString = "destination={0}&flags=0&username={1}";
            bodyString += "&password={2}&SubmitCreds=Log+On&";
            bodyString += "forcedownlevel=0&trusted=0";
            bodyString = string.Format(bodyString, server,
                                        userName, password);

            var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyString);

            request.ContentLength = body.Length;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
            stream.Close();

            //Console.WriteLine((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.Cookies.Count < 2) throw
                new AuthenticationException("Failed to login to OWA!");
            return response.Cookies;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your code, and put only that section where the error arises, not the whole of it, nobody's going to read it !

Comment: i added a section that shows the line that when the code is debugged hops to my catch statement. its the "Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();" line. Honestly though i know that the reason it is doing that is because im getting the 440 error. what im not sure of is why im getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpWebRequest pass credentials to next HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443667/httpwebrequest-pass-credentials-to-next-httpwebrequest)

[How to insert CookieCollection to CookieContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546369/how-to-insert-cookiecollection-to-cookiecontainer)

[Why is one cookie missed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640806/why-is-one-cookie-missed)

Answer (score 1):

The server issues a `HTTP/1.1 440` Login Timeout, whenever FBA is enabled and there is a HTTP request or a WebDav request made against exchange 2003/2007 ..Here's some [sample code](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2004/12/Access-the-Exchange-store-via-WebDAV-with-Form-Based-Authentication-turned-on-Updated.aspx) and here are details on [FBA](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/tutorial/formsbasedauthentication.html)

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307164/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-440-login-timeout)

Comment: thanks for the information Tarun but i would like to not use a third party code/plugin/api.